# How to fix the reconnection time in BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a problem with disconnect and connect the BLE device with my phone. In my phone, I have a disconnect button. If the phone and device are connecting, I will press the device to disconnect them. It was disconnected successfully. However, when I call the connect function, it takes 10 seconds to reconnect. This is my code and logcat. Could you help me to reduce the reconnection time?

```
//Click button disconnect
public void onClickDisconnect(View view) {
    mBluetoothLeService.disconnect();
}
```

Then I connect again, I will call the connect function as follows:

```
 public boolean connect(final String address) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
            return false;
        }

        // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
        if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
                && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
            if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        if (device == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
            return false;
        }
        // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
        // parameter to false.

        //mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, true, mGattCallback);
        new Handler(getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (device != null) {
                    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), true, mGattCallback);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

This is my logcat

```
10-27 23:19:37.284 13162-13162/com.example.blechat D/BluetoothGatt: close()
10-27 23:19:37.284 13162-13162/com.example.blechat D/BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=6
10-27 23:19:37.314 13162-13162/com.example.blechat D/BluetoothLeService: Trying to create a new connection.
10-27 23:19:37.354 13162-13162/com.example.blechat D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: 00:02:5B:00:15:33, auto: true
10-27 23:19:37.354 13162-13162/com.example.blechat D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
10-27 23:19:37.354 13162-13162/com.example.blechat D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=23513bb1-c4fc-4203-ad3a-d58c38f2ddfb
10-27 23:19:37.394 13162-13706/com.example.blechat D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6
10-27 23:19:42.374 13162-13162/com.example.blechat D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
10-27 23:19:48.994 13162-13162/com.example.blechat D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
10-27 23:19:56.704 13162-13706/com.example.blechat D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=6 device=00:02:5B:00:15:33
```

Answer (score -1):

When the client sends a connect request on Link Layer level, it waits for an advertisement packet from the device indicating that the server is in connectable state. This can take some time, depending on the advertisement interval of the server.

So the way to decrease the connection (and reconnection) time would typically be to increase the frequency of advertisements on the BLE device. But keep in mind that this will also increase the energy consumption of the device. In most cases, an interval of 10-20 seconds (and thus, a mean reconnection duration of 5-10 seconds) is acceptable if you can save much energy during the rest of the time where the device is unused.

You can, however, configure the device in a way that shortly after a disconnect, the advertisement interval is set to a much lower value, returning to the original one after a certain time span. If quick reconnection is a frequent use case, this could be the way to go.

If you really need fast reaction time, however, maybe BLE is not the best way to go, and classic Bluetooth would be preferrable. Bluetooth Low Energy is optimized for low energy consumption, not for speed.

Comment: Thats difficult to say. Typically, it is done on the BLE device. What device are you using? There should be a function like "Set Advertising Parameters" or "Set Advertising Interval" or similar on the BLE API of the device. From the phone, however, I doubt if this is possible.